# Dictionary properties are always null despite dictionaries being instantiated

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, resx

To begin with, I have two projects under the names of `Components` and `WindowsFormsApplication5` as part of my solution (there are more, but those are irrelevant). The dictionaries I am referring to are in `Components`, defined as follows, along-with their properties -:

```
 Dictionary<int, ButtonBase> RespMCQ, DispMCQ; //<Question Number, Checkbox/Radiobutton>
 Dictionary<int, List<ButtonBase>> RespMSQ, DispMSQ;
 public Dictionary<int, ButtonBase> MCQResp
 {
     get
     {
         return RespMCQ;
     }
     set
     {
         RespMCQ = value;
     }
 }
 public Dictionary<int, List<ButtonBase>> MSQResponse
 {
     get
     {
         return RespMSQ;
     }
     set
     {
         RespMSQ = value;
     }
 }
 public Dictionary<int, ButtonBase> MCQDisplay
 {
     get
     {
         return DispMCQ;
     }
     set
     {
         DispMCQ = value;
     }
 }
 public Dictionary<int, List<ButtonBase>> MSQDisplay
 {
     get
     {
         return DispMSQ;
     }
     set
     {
         DispMSQ = value;
     }
 }
```

The dictionaries are instantiated in the constructor of `QuestionDisplay.cs`, which is part of the `Components` project (this is where they reside). This is shown as follows -:

```
public QuestionDisplay()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RespMCQ = new Dictionary<int, ButtonBase>();
    DispMCQ = new Dictionary<int, ButtonBase>();
    RespMSQ = new Dictionary<int, List<ButtonBase>>();
    DispMSQ = new Dictionary<int, List<ButtonBase>>();
    ....
}
```

In `Form1.cs` of `WindowsFormsApplication5` (I did not choose this name, pardon me if it sounds bland), I am using the properties I mentioned. There are no namespace issues and compilation occurs as normal.

During the `Form_Load` of `Form1`, however, when I refer to these properties, they throw a `NullReferenceException` saying -:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The first occurrence of these properties is in a method called `WorkFlowPanel(string S, QuestionContainerState obj)` which is called at the time of form load -:

```
 if (QuesTypes[i].Equals("MCQ"))
 {
    string text = "";
    for (int ansCount = 0; ansCount < questions[i].Options.Count(); ansCount++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(K.Key).Equals(ansCount + 1))
        {
            text = questions[i].Options[ansCount];
            break;
        }
    }
    questionDisplay1.MCQResp.Add(i, new CustomRadio { optionId = Convert.ToInt32(K.Key), Checked = true, Text = text }); //Using anonymous class
 }
 else if (QuesTypes[i].Equals("MSQ") || QuesTypes[i].Equals("Linked"))
 {
     var storeoptions = K.Key.Split(':');
     questionDisplay1.MSQResponse.Add(i, new List<ButtonBase>());
     for (int s = 0; s < storeoptions.Count(); s++)
     {
         questionDisplay1.MSQResponse[i].Add(new CustomChecks { optionId = Convert.ToInt32(storeoptions[s]), Checked = true, Text = questions[i].Options[Convert.ToInt32(storeoptions[s])] });
     }
 }
```

To my surprise, on debugging, I found that the properties are always null despite the dictionaries being instantiated. Now this problem has a bit of a history which I will have to delve into, to provide context.

I was earlier battling with a `Could not find a type for a name. The type was System.Collections.Dictionary...` bug which was occurring in `Form1.resx` (I cannot recall the entire error). Apparently the dictionary properties were being **serialized** into binary format and encoded as base64 in the resx file, as follows -:

```
<data name="MCQDisplay" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
<value>
        AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAEAQAA....
</value>
<data name="MSQDisplay" .....>
....
....
```

I followed a solution I found on Stackoverflow, which told me to copy the code back into an older version. This is the fix I had been applying since then. I found that if I removed these entries (which the compiler error asked me to do), the dictionary properties would always be null. I feel this is tied to my current scenario. It so happened that during the copy-back operation, the resx file entries somehow vanished.

Since then, it has never thrown this compiler error. I tried everything, including the use of `ResXResourceWriter` to regenerate the entries. It's like they're not even acknowledged, and instead of the error, I'm told during run-time that the dictionary properties are always null! One person on IRC suggested that the error used to occur because `ButtonBase` is not serializable, even though `Dictionary` in itself is. Well, I never asked the compiler to serialize the dictionaries. I wonder why that even happened.

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me resolve this damning bug. I also had this vague solution in my head that instead of storing `ButtonBase` children as values, I could store class objects instead which have properties mirroring the text, optionId and checked properties of the `ButtonBase` child. However, I am thinking of this as a last resort.

**EDIT_1**: I don't know if this is relevant, but I found these entries in `Form1.Designer.cs` -:

```
this.questionDisplay1.MCQDisplay = ((System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase>)(resources.GetObject("questionDisplay1.MCQDisplay")));
this.questionDisplay1.MCQResp = ((System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase>)(resources.GetObject("questionDisplay1.MCQResp")));
this.questionDisplay1.MSQDisplay = ((System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase>>)(resources.GetObject("questionDisplay1.MSQDisplay")));
this.questionDisplay1.MSQResponse = ((System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase>>)(resources.GetObject("questionDisplay1.MSQResponse")));
```

Do I have to remove these or modify them in some way? I feel these are somehow related to Matthew's answer.

**EDIT_2**: I managed to solve this problem by applying the following -:

1. Matthew Watson's non-serialization fix - incase the compiler tried to serialize the dictionary properties again.
2. I commented out the entries in the `Form1.Designer.cs`, the ones that I mentioned above.

I am accepting Matthew's answer because I feel the non-serialization fix is relevant.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the code of the constructor in the class Components, how do you instantiate an instance of this class and how do you try to access the dictionaries

Comment: @Steve : Adding straightaway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these properties both public and members of a class derived from `Form`, `UserControl` or `Control`?

If so, it is possible that the Forms designer will be trying to serialize the properties to the form's Designer.cs file. (In fact, from what you said, it's entirely *probable*.)

To stop that from happening you can use the [`DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx) to prevent it, for example:

```
[
    Browsable(false),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)
]

public MyType MyPropertyWhichMustNotBeSerialized
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

You'll have to edit away any bad stuff it's already put in the ".Designer.cs" file though - adding this attribute might not make it go away automatically.

If you haven't regularly checking if you need to add this attribute, I think you might want to go through *all* your public properties in any classes derived directly or indirectly from `Control`, and add this attribute where necessary.

---

For the problem will the null references; is it possible that `FormLoad()` is being called as a side-effect of the call to `InitialiseComponent()`? That would cause a null reference error.

To be safest you should use backing fields for your properties instead of automatic properties.

Then instead of initialising the fields in a constructor, initialise them right where you declare the fields, like this:

```
private Dictionary<int, ButtonBase>       respMCQ = new Dictionary<int, ButtonBase>();
private Dictionary<int, ButtonBase>       dispMCQ = new Dictionary<int, ButtonBase>();
private Dictionary<int, List<ButtonBase>> respMSQ = new Dictionary<int, List<ButtonBase>>();
private Dictionary<int, List<ButtonBase>> dispMSQ = new Dictionary<int, List<ButtonBase>>();
```

That way they are guaranteed to be initialised before any constructor is called.

Comment: The properties are indeed public, but the class they reside in is derived from `UserControl`. I am still going to try your fix however. Will clean the entries present in the resx file first.

Comment: @UncleDolan I should also have said `UserControl` - that is affected too

Comment: Tried this, but there is no difference. The nullref exception is still being thrown, and it is happening at the line where I try to add an entry into `questionDisplay1.MSQResponse`.

Comment: @UncleDolan I suspect there is more than one bug and this has only fixed one of them.

Comment: I am beginning to think the same. This fix would have worked if I had come here earlier with the `Form1.resx` compiler error...it seems that I am too late! By the way, does it serialize to `Designer.cs` as well? I saw it being serialized to `Form1.resx`.

Comment: @UncleDolan I have another idea; I've edited my answer with it.

Comment: I think I should add that before moving these instantiations to the constructor, I was originally instantiating them at the time of declaration. There was no change when I made this move and the exception was still being thrown.